# I inherited code in python; am I right thinking this is a recursive call which adds to the stack _forever_?

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I inherited python code which has a function as follow:

```
async def client(host, port, application_state, queue):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
    try:
        for state in application_state:
            while not reader.at_eof():
               ...do something with the data just read...
    except Exception as e:
        await client(host, port, application_state, queue)
    finally:
        writer.close()
```

From what I understand, any time the connection to the server is lost, the reader is going to generate an exception. At that point, the function calls itself. If that happens often, it adds to the stack *forever*.

I was thinking that using a `while` loop would resolve the issue.

```
async def client(host, port, application_state, queue):
    repeat = true
    while repeat
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
        try:
            for state in application_state:
                while not reader.at_eof():
                    ...do something with the data just read...
        except Exception as e:
            # repeat the while loop instead of calling function
        finally:
            writer.close()
            repeat = false
```

My question: Is there an issue in the first example? Will the stack really be increased on each disconnection/re-connection? If so, will the `while` loop fix the issue?

Comment: I don't think it will, since the connect is outside the try block? I could be wrong, but I think it will attempt to reconnect once, and if that connection breaks return to the first invocation. That said, this feels like a very awko way of doing this.

Comment: Yup, you're completely right. Every Exception will add a call to `client` to the stack. A while loop is definitely better than recursion here, especially if you expect this code to run long enough to have many disconnections.

Comment: Your code is definitely an improvement over the original, although the recursion only occurs after the actual read, so it wouldn't occur very often that the service will be re-read so often that the max recursion depth is actually reached. Still, the original is bad code and yours is better.